# Halloween Themed Activity

Tags: teen, party, programming

I am interested in a large scale Halloween Activity primarily young adults, I wanted to show some Halloween spirit so I picked the movie Rocky Horror Picture Show.

I want to have the movie playing, but I also want to have side activities going on is there any other suggestion for activities that I can come up with that would celebrate Halloween that I can do while this movie is playing

Comment: How is this related to parenting?

Comment: I am an upcoming parent and I am organizing an event for the teenagers around the area where I live

Comment: I agree with @KaiQing. Based on the given information, this is not actually a parenting question. Also, showing Rocky Horror Picture Show to a group of teens for a Halloween party seems like a bit of a bad decision in my book. Are there parents aware this will be shown?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it's more about Halloween parties than parenting.

Comment: It was about the right to do as a parent, with organizing a Halloween party. The party is already scheduled thanks to the answer I received and the advice I was able to program it accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Traditional Halloween and harvest games

- Bobbing for apples
- Donut on a string eating contest.
- Pumpkin carving ( here is a template https://www.zombiepumpkins.com/dr-frank-n-furter-pumpkin-pattern/254/)
- Halloween Craft Project

### Activities related to the movie

- Rocky Horror Picture Show Trivia
- Costume Contest (could be a bad idea depending on the group)
- Pause the move and have the kids guess the next word

Winner gets candy!